# Invalid Date with datejs

Tags: javascript, vuejs3

I need to convert string to date.

But I don't understand why the end date is not converted from a string. Then I decided to use the daysJs library, but it gave the same thing

```js
let date={
end:"15-10-2022",
start:"05-10-2022",
}
let range = {
        start:new Date(date.start),
        end: new Date(date.end),
};
      
console.log(range)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running the code snippet embedded in Stack, I can see that your `end` property is null, presumably because the formattign for the dates is `MM-DD-YYYY` and you're formatting them as `DD-MM-YYYY`. The simplest solution is to **Swap your month and day** in the date. Otherwise, just use **MomentJS** for its simplification of working with dates.

Formatting DD-MM-YYYY without moment:

```js
let date = {
    end: '15-10-2022',
    start: '05-10-2022'
};
let range = {
    start: new Date(date.start.split('-').reverse().join('-')),
    end: new Date(date.end.split('-').reverse().join('-'))
};
console.log(range);
```

Formatting DD-MM-YYYY with moment:

```js
let date = {
    end: '15-10-2022',
    start: '05-10-2022'
};
let range = {
    start: moment(date.start, 'DD-MM-YYYY'),
    end: moment(date.end, 'DD-MM-YYYY')
};
console.log(range);
```

Answer (score 0):

first number is month so 15 is undefined

```js
let date={
end:"10-10-2022",
start:"05-10-2022",
}
let range = {
        start:new Date(date.start),
        end: new Date(date.end),
};
      
console.log(range)
```

Answer (score 0):

The date format is wrong. Use `YYYY-MM-DD`